# How to setup filtered transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

**Configuration/Setup**

PUBLISHER: SQL Server at branch premises having only specific branch data (ex: branch ID 135)

SUBSCRIBER: SQL Server (live at data center) used by application having data for all the branches.

The publisher needs to send the data changes (only for branch ID 135) from local branch to the subscriber (the data center SQL Server). The subscriber must store the replicated data from branch ID 135 without affecting any other branch data from the live tables.

I have configured Transactional Replication to replicate the changes performed on the Transaction tables on the publisher, which stores data only for 1 branch with Branch_ID 135.

The distributor runs on the publisher. I have filtered the publication tables/articles on Branch_ID=135.

**Issue/Problem**

Subscriber data gets fully refreshed and all the branch id data gets deleted. The Subscriber is left with data only for Branch ID 135, which is replicated from the Publisher.

I have a test server to perform this configuration/testing.

Can you please help me out where am I missing my Replication configuration?